# How to limit the amount of data returned from a JSON file using fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have this `fetch` statement that returns 19 building names, but I only want 10; the following is what I attempted, but I still get 19 building names.

```
fetchBuildings(energyProgramId) {
  fetch(`http://localhost:1001/api/energyprograms/${energyProgramId}/buildings/?results=10`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        buildings: json,
      })
    });
}
```

Is there something extra I need to add?

Comment: That depends entirely on the API: they return what they're programmed to return.

Comment: If a http api recieves a query parameter that it doesn't understand, that parameter is typically just ignored. So presumably the api backend doesn't understand `results=10`. You should consult the documentation for the api framework you are using. Or you could add information about the backend and tag this question with the relevant tag.

Comment: I see you have `results=10`. We have to see the server side code for this. From what you're saying you're not returning 10.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No different from `fetch` to `XHR` or `axios` or anything else. actually, no different from `react` or `angular` or `vue` or anything else.

This is an API that backend developers wrote it and it is based on `REST` API, so when you call it as `GET` or `POST` and anything else you just fetch the JSON that the backend developers designed it. ***BUT***

There is a new technology that name is [`GraphQL`](https://graphql.org/). you can call API and then you just fetch the JSON what you want. Also, it must be implemented in backend but it is possible.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve my problem by implementing a condition into the API (the back-end) ... thank you again for the response.

Comment: What about when using the fetch() method? Does that actually count as doing a normal GET request? Is it just like an esNext wrapper for GET or something?

Answer (score 17):

Here is an example:

1.fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')

The above URL gives array of objects with 100 elements because it originally is an array of 100 elements.

2.fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/?_limit=10')
This URL gives array of objects with 10 elements.

Notice the difference?

I only did this : **?_limit=10** ----> Add any number in place of 10 and hopefully you will get desired results.

Comment: Works like charm! I don't see this being mentioned in their [website](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide.html) too. lol

Comment: Somehow this worked for fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?_limit=4') but did not in case of this fetch('https://api.github.com/users?_limit=4'). Any clue on this?

Comment: How do we specify a range?

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer already points out the best/most normal solution would be to change on the backend how the API returns data. Typically REST API's support query parameters such as `limit` and `start` or `page` and `resultsPerPage`.

If this is not available - e.g. when you're fetching an external resource - an alternative which is often supported by static file servers and sometimes by API's is the `Range` header which allows you to retrieve only a specific byte range of the resource (do note, in the case that an API supports this it will still load the entire resource on the server, but it will not transmit the entire resource). An example with fetch would look like

```
fetch('', { headers: { range: 'bytes=0-1000'} })
```

When doing this on XML or JSON resources it can be somewhat difficult to work with, but with for example CSV files it's ideal.

Answer (score -1):

It's not closely bound up with React. If you need less data you must reduce  data before set the state.

```
const reducedBuildings = [];

fetch(`http://localhost:1001/api/energyprograms/${energyProgramId}/buildings/?results=10`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    json.forEach(building => {
        if (reducedBuildings.length < 10) {
            reducedBuildings.push(building);
        }
    });
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true,
      buildings: reducedBuildings,
    })
  });
```

Comment: I think this is not the answer, because the owner of the question wanna fetch less data not, surely he now about changing data before the `setState`.

Comment: Yes, but for less data, not need client side changes. Need some changes in server side for less data, the URL parameter, as I see is not currently working.